# eBox / CUPS - HP printer doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, cups

I'd like to get a HP OfficeJet Pro K8600 working.
The server is an Ubuntu 8.10 running an eBox 1.4.9. CUPS is 1.3.7.

I can add a new printer to the eBox printer sharing, the printer is listed in the CUPS web interface, but CUPS shows "Printer not connected; will retry in 30 seconds..."

The printer is local accessible in /dev/usb/lp0 and when I "echo" something to the device it reacts very, very slowly, but prints at the end.

When I try to print a test page (from the eBox or CUPS interface or a samba client) I can see the job in the eBox and CUPS interface, but it looks like the job is not being processed.

The rights for accessing the printer are set correctly through eBox.

When I list all available printers in CUPS I see two entries:

- HP Officejet Pro K8600 (HP Officejet
  Pro K8600 USB #1)
- HP Officejet Pro
  K8600 (HP Officejet Pro K8600 USB
  TH9B4220C4 HPLIP)

Shouldn't there just be one printer available?
I already tried to reinstall all components.
How can I find the error?
Why tells CUPS that the "Printer not connected"?
TY in advance.